# How to use PyMC (v4.0.1) with statsmodels to estimate state space models?

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, pymc, state-space

I am trying to use PyMC (v4.0.1) with statsmodels to estimate state-space models. I am following this example that uses PyMC3:

https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.12.0/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_pymc3.html

The example makes use of the `pm.DensityDist()` function and apparently the API has changed. And PyMC uses Aesara instead of Theano and I have no idea if that matters.

As a working example, here is my attempt to simulate and estimate an AR(1) process:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pymc as pm
import aesara.tensor as at
from scipy.signal import lfilter

# Generate artificial data
nobs = int(1e3)
true_phi = np.r_[0.5]
true_sigma = 0.5**0.5

np.random.seed(1234)
disturbances = np.random.normal(0, true_sigma, size=(nobs,))
endog = lfilter([1], np.r_[1, -true_phi], disturbances)

# Initialize model
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog, order=(1, 0, 0))


# Helper functions copied. Do not know how they work
class Loglike(at.Op):

    itypes = [at.dvector] # expects a vector of parameter values when called
    otypes = [at.dscalar] # outputs a single scalar value (the log likelihood)

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.score = Score(self.model)

    def perform(self, node, inputs, outputs):
        theta, = inputs  # contains the vector of parameters
        llf = self.model.loglike(theta)
        outputs[0][0] = np.array(llf) # output the log-likelihood

    def grad(self, inputs, g):
        # the method that calculates the gradients - it actually returns the
        # vector-Jacobian product - g[0] is a vector of parameter values
        theta, = inputs  # our parameters
        out = [g[0] * self.score(theta)]
        return out


class Score(at.Op):
    itypes = [at.dvector]
    otypes = [at.dvector]

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def perform(self, node, inputs, outputs):
        theta, = inputs
        outputs[0][0] = self.model.score(theta)
        
        
loglike = Loglike(mod)

# Set sampling params
ndraws = 3000  # number of draws from the distribution
nburn = 600   # number of "burn-in points" (which will be discarded)

# Sample from posterior
with pm.Model():
    # Priors
    arL1 = pm.Uniform('ar.L1', -0.99, 0.99)
    sigma2 = pm.InverseGamma('sigma2', 2, 4)

    # convert variables to tensor vectors
    theta = at.as_tensor_variable([arL1, sigma2])

    # use a DensityDist (use a lamdba function to "call" the Op)
    pm.DensityDist('likelihood', theta, logp = lambda v: loglike(v))

    # Draw samples
    trace = pm.sample(ndraws, tune=nburn, discard_tuned_samples=True, cores=1)
```

The error is in the call to `pm.sample()`.

```
---> 74     trace = pm.sample(ndraws, tune=nburn, discard_tuned_samples=True, cores=1)
```

But the error message suggests that the issue has something to do with the likelihood function:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I've tried a bunch of things, but I'm at a loss. I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue fixed by replacing:

`pm.DensityDist('likelihood', theta, logp = lambda v: loglike(v))`

with

`pm.Potential('likelihood', loglike(theta))`

Here's the full working code:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pymc as pm
import aesara.tensor as at
from scipy.signal import lfilter

# Generate artificial data
nobs = int(1e3)
true_phi = np.r_[0.5]
true_sigma = 0.5**0.5

np.random.seed(1234)
disturbances = np.random.normal(0, true_sigma, size=(nobs,))
endog = lfilter([1], np.r_[1, -true_phi], disturbances)

# Initialize model
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog, order=(1, 0, 0))


# Helper functions copied. Do not know how they work
class Loglike(at.Op):

    itypes = [at.dvector] # expects a vector of parameter values when called
    otypes = [at.dscalar] # outputs a single scalar value (the log likelihood)

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.score = Score(self.model)

    def perform(self, node, inputs, outputs):
        theta, = inputs  # contains the vector of parameters
        llf = self.model.loglike(theta)
        outputs[0][0] = np.array(llf) # output the log-likelihood

    def grad(self, inputs, g):
        # the method that calculates the gradients - it actually returns the
        # vector-Jacobian product - g[0] is a vector of parameter values
        theta, = inputs  # our parameters
        out = [g[0] * self.score(theta)]
        return out


class Score(at.Op):
    itypes = [at.dvector]
    otypes = [at.dvector]

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def perform(self, node, inputs, outputs):
        theta, = inputs
        outputs[0][0] = self.model.score(theta)
        
        
loglike = Loglike(mod)

# Set sampling params
ndraws = 3000  # number of draws from the distribution
nburn = 600   # number of "burn-in points" (which will be discarded)

# Sample from posterior
with pm.Model():
    # Priors
    arL1 = pm.Uniform('ar.L1', -0.99, 0.99)
    sigma2 = pm.InverseGamma('sigma2', 2, 4)

    # convert variables to tensor vectors
    theta = at.as_tensor_variable([arL1, sigma2])

    # use a DensityDist (use a lamdba function to "call" the Op)
    pm.Potential('likelihood', loglike(theta))

    # Draw samples
    trace = pm.sample(ndraws, tune=nburn, discard_tuned_samples=True, cores=1)
```

Comment: To make the code work for `pymc` (5.0.1), change `import aesara.tensor as at` to `import pytensor.tensor as at`.

Comment: Thanks! I will leave the answer as-is because the question was in regards to PyMC v4, but as you suggest, it looks like we use PyTensor with PyMC now: [https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/stable/learn/core_notebooks/pymc_pytensor.html](https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/stable/learn/core_notebooks/pymc_pytensor.html)